# Who has deleted MySQL user from management console?

Tags: mysql

How can I find who has removed a SQL login from MySQL instance?

Checked event viewer but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is no audit trail, so you are out of luck this time.  For the future:

Plan A:  Build some kind of audit trail.

Plan B:  Look for an audit plugin, such as PAM.